# Django - Get centroid of polygon in geoJSON format

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postgis, django-rest-framework-gis

I'm building a REST API to manage geo-related data. 
My front-end developer wants to retrieve the centroid of polygons, depending on zoom level, in `geoJSON` format.

My polygon model is as follows:

```
...
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
class Polygon(geomodels.Model):
    fk_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True) 
    func_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    coordinates = geomodels.PolygonField(srid=3857)
    properties = JSONField(default={})
```

The API currently returns things like this:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
 {
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [[[..]]]
      }
  }]
```

And I use `rest_framework_gis.serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer` to serialize my data.

I see the following ways to get the centroid:

1. Add a column centroid to my model: *I don't want to do this*
2. Create a database view of my model: *Django does not manage database views and I don't want to write a custom migration*
3. Use the same model and add an `extra(...)` to my orm statement: *I tried but things get hard in or before serialization, because in the model the type is `Polygon`, and the centroid is a `Point`. The error is the following:*

   ```
   TypeError: 
       Cannot set Polygon SpatialProxy (POLYGON) with value of type:
       <class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.point.Point'>
   ```

The expected output should be:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
 {
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [..]
      }
  }]
```

What is your opinion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of the following methods:

1. [`AsGeoJSON`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.AsGeoJSON), which

   > Accepts a single geographic field or expression and returns a GeoJSON representation of the geometry.
2. [`Centroid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Centroid) which

   > Accepts a single geographic field or expression and returns the centroid value of the geometry.
3. [`.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) which

   > Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of query expressions. 
   > [...] 
   > Each argument to `annotate()` is an annotation that will be added to each object in the QuerySet that is returned.

---

**Example:**

The following query:

```
Polygon.objects.annotate(geometry=AsGeoJSON(Centroid('coordinates')))
```

will add a field named `'geometry'` to the `Polygon` queryset which will contain the centroid calculated from the `coordinates` field of every `Polygon` object of your given model.